# Unable to start Resin application server

Tags: java, server, resin

I have two resin web servers(41,47) in same folder. Actually am changing server version from 47 to 41 when I deployed and started project in 41 its hitting some error like below,

```
[admin@localhost bin]$ ./resin.sh start;
 Resin/4.0.41 can't start -server 'app-0' for watchdog at 127.0.0.1:6600.
 Unexpected resin.home mismatch:
 CLI resin.home: /home/admin/resin-pro-4.0.41/
 watchdog resin.home: /home/admin/resin-4.0.46/
```

can anyone help me out this?

Answer (score 2):

After hard struggle I got answer for this, moving resin to some other directory will disappear this issue. simple! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix resix.xml

```html
<server-multi id-prefix="app-" address-list="${app_servers}" port="6800" watchdog-port="6601"/>
```